# Looking for a simple file manager for Mac

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation

I am looking for a simple file manager for Mac. My requirements are:

- support the usual grid view
- show the file size of highlighted files
- **does not truncate long file names - adjusts the grid instead**

Something like the example on the bottom right sourced from this question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169221/how-to-make-thunar-show-short-file-names).

[image]

Unfortunately, I only find alternative file managers that use a list view. Is there an file manager that meets these requirements?

Comment: Do the suggestions in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180418 help with the long file name wrapping?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work on MacOS 10.12.6 :-(

Comment: Google "Finder Alternative," which is what these are usually called. There are several out there (none of which I have ever used) that might have a similar option to what you need.

Comment: Have you tried any of the alternatives listed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-finder ?

Comment: I have tried some of the free alternatives, but they all seem to follow a dual pane, list layout, which I do not like particularly. I may use a paid one, but only after knowing it does what I want

Comment: You might want to look at apps that index pdfs like papers https://www.readcube.com/papers/mac/

Answer (score 1):

I never came across a file manager that adjust the grid for long names. However if you want to go further than the Finder you can give a try at [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/), [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) or [Commander](https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html), they're all great file management tools.

Comment: The problem is that I have lots of folders full of files with long file names (mostly scientific papers) and they all look unreadable without an adjustable grid. I will try the ones you mentioned - I had already tried Commander One and it did not seem to do this (plus it defaults to a dual pane view which I do not like very much)